# Why three of my jquerys cannot be loaded during my Wordpress theme development

Tags: jquery, wordpress, twitter-bootstrap, themes, flexslider

I want to do a wordpress theme based on my website already developed by now. I have only one page website which mainly uses a jquery plugin 'Ascensor', and I also chose to use boostrap as the framework of my website. The website works really perfectly on my computer as a static page. However, I met a big problem when I want to convert it to a wordpress theme.

The html, css can be sucessfully loaded in wordpress, but three of my jquery cannot be loaded. 
(***I have four jquery, and "bootstrap.js" is the only one can be loaded successfully***).

Here is my code for the function.js:

```
<?php 
function my_scripts_method() {

wp_enqueue_script( 'bootstrap', get_template_directory_uri() . '/css/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js', array( 'jquery' ) );
wp_enqueue_script( 'ascensor', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/jquery.ascensor.js', array( 'jquery' ) );
wp_enqueue_script( 'backstretch', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/jquery.backstretch.min.js', array( 'jquery' ) );
wp_enqueue_script( 'flexslider', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/jquery.flexslider.js', array( 'jquery' ) );

}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'my_scripts_method' );
?>
```

and I have already put these code in my footer.php:

```
<?php wp_footer(); ?>               

<script type="text/javascript">
  $(function(){
    SyntaxHighlighter.all();
  });
  $(window).load(function(){
    $('#carousel').flexslider({
      animation: "slide",
      controlNav: false,
      animationLoop: false,
      slideshow: false,
      itemWidth: 210,
      itemMargin: 5,
      asNavFor: '#slider'
    });

    $('#slider').flexslider({
      animation: "slide",
      controlNav: false,
      animationLoop: false,
      slideshow: false,
      sync: "#carousel",
      start: function(slider){
        $('#loading').removeClass('loading');
      }
    });
  });
</script>
<script>
 $("#first").backstretch("<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>img/bg2.png",{fade:1500});
</script>
<script>
    $('#ascensorBuilding').ascensor({ChildType: 'section',Direction:"chocolate", AscensorMap: "1|2 & 2|2 & 3|2 & 4|2 & 2|1 & 3|1",Overflow:"hidden", QueuedDirection: "x",Queued: true,Time: 500,});
</script>
```

***The bootstrap.min.js can be loaded successfully, the other three cannot, this is the problem.***

Comment: As I know, the wp_footer() should be the last thing before the closing body tag (a requirement by WP). Also I have already encoutered issues with wp_enqueue_script which I simply resolved by calling my scripts the normal way, inside script tag before wp_footer(). Good luck.

Comment: look at the paths, bootstrap loads from `/css/`, the failed scripts references to `/js/` ...

Answer (score 0):

still feel confused, still thanks to whiteletters and blankspaces, and davidkonrad did some comments for my post.

finally I choose to use /js/... in header.php to solve this problem, but still dont know what is wrong for my function.php.